# How do I change all values of a field in c# entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How do I change all values of a field in c# entity framework?

For example I want to change all values of a field from 0 to 1?

In other words:

I have a table with fields named: `FId` (primary key), `FQuestion`, `FAnswer`, `CId` (foreign key), `LId`. That all values of `LId` field are equal to int value `0` and I want to change them all to `1` in C# Entity Framework.

Comment: Could you clarify your question and give some more info?

Comment: yes, thx, I have a table with fields named: FId (primary key), FQuestion, FAnswer, CId (foreign key), LId. That all values of LId field are equal to "0" and I want to change them all to "1" in C# Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
tableRows.Where(r => r.lId == 0).ForEach(r => r.lId = 1);
```

Comment: I couldn't do that; plz explain more! thx a lot

Comment: Why cann't you do that? Please show your code

Comment: //YOUR CODE:
            //tableRows.Where(r => r.lId == 0).ForEach(r => r.lId = 1);

            //I changed it to:
            var rSearch=database.tblFishes0.Where(r => r.LId == 0).ToArray();
            foreach(int test in rSearch[3])//Then I got this error message:
            //Error 1 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'WindowsFormsApplication2.tblFishes0' because 'WindowsFormsApplication2.tblFishes0' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

            {

            }

Comment: you have an error in your foreach: you have foreach(int test in **rSearch[3]** ), but it must be foreach(int test in **rSearch** )

Comment: var rSearch=database.tblFishes0.Where(r => r.LId == 0).ToArray();
            foreach(var test in rSearch)
            {                                
                rSearch[3] = 1; //Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'WindowsFormsApplication2.tblFishes0'
            }            
            database.SaveChanges();

Comment: I tried that. but it didn't work! thanks a lot.

Comment: thank you for your attention

Comment: ok, rSearch realy is not an int :) Try change foreach to: foreach (var item in rSearch). Note: item is of type tblFishes0 or something like that, not int. So, if you need to get some property of item, just type item.SomeProperty

Comment: THANKS A LOT MY DEAR FRIEND; I TRIED THE FOLLOWING CODE AND MY CODE WORKED:
var rSearch=database.tblFishes0.Where(r => r.LId == 0).ToArray();
foreach(var item in rSearch)
{                
    item.LId = 1;
}            
database.SaveChanges();

Comment: You are welcome :) And don't forget to give me a vote :):):)

Answer (score 0):

You can you `ForEach()`

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

values.ForEach(v => v.field = 1);
```

This works for any collection type.

#### Update:

In Entity Framework you can use

```
using System.Data.Entity;

await _db.TableName.ForEachAsync(v => v.Field = 1);
```

At the end you have to call `await _db.SaveChangesAsync();`

Comment: thx, but I couldn't use that; plz explain more